# Unable to use Tailwindcss in codesandbox

Tags: tailwind-css, codesandbox

Can anyone please guide why tailwindcss isn't applying styles in this react codesandbox?
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/runtime-pine-78z6th?file=%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.css. I installed tailwind through "dependencies" section and then added following code to `styles.css` file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you did not follow all the steps to integrate Tailwind CSS into your Vite React project. [As per the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite):

1. (From step 2)
   Run the following command in the terminal to generate boilerplate `postcss.config.js` and `tailwind.config.js` files:

   ```bash
   npx tailwindcss init -p
   ```
2. (From step 3)
   Add `src/App.jsx` to the `content` file globs array in `tailwind.config.js` :

   ```js
   /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
   module.exports = {
     content: ["src/App.jsx"],
   ```
3. `bg-blue` used in `App.jsx` would not resolve to a Tailwind class name with the default configuration, so I modified the Tailwind configuration to include `blue` as a color:

   ```js
   /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
   module.exports = {
     …
     theme: {
       extend: {
         colors: {
           blue: {
             DEFAULT: "blue",
   ```

See Tailwind working with the above steps undertaken in [this forked CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/stoic-sinoussi-n5zmpf).